# Getting Scheduled Alarms from Default Alarm Clock App (specifically Clock on Android)

Tags: react-native, expo, alarmmanager, clock, alarm

I am developing a React Native project using expo, and I'm wondering if there is a way that I can somehow view recurring alarms that have been set on Android (possibly ios as well), and also am wondering if it is possible to trigger an event somehow in my app once an alarm from the default clock app has been dismissed or snoozed?

For instance, execute some code after the user has dismissed their recurring daily wakeup alarm from their clock app.

I am currently leaning towards possibly implementing my own alarm clock feature in my app and recommending the user to use my implementation instead as a way to get access to these things if they are not possible through the OS.

I have not been able to find any information on any of this